# Adding a flag to CSC command line

Tags: c#, com, manifest

I have a C# project in VS2010 which generates a DLL with a COM object inside.

For registration free COM to work, I would like to embed a manifest as a Win32 resource. I therefore need to pass `/win32res:blah.res` to the `csc` command line used to build the DLL. I can generate the `.res` file with a pre build event.

But I can't manage to do it. I sounds completely insane, but it seems there is no simple way to pass a custom flag to `csc`. I realize that `.csproj` files are MSBuild files, and I imagine there is a **simple** way to modify it to my needs, but I can't find anything relevant (and this is driving me crazy).

Comment: Have you tried Win32Resource from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5c8athz.aspx ?

Comment: @MarcGravell: The intellisense (and the DTD for MsBuild projects) say one should use Win32ResourceFile, which does not work. I'll check with  Win32Resource.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Weirdly, it works with `Win32Resource`, even if the intellisense goes all red-wiggly. You can put this as an answer I'd be glad to upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is exposed in the IDE.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Resource File option.

But don't do it this way, you'll get in trouble with the regular manifest that gets embedded in the program.  Use Project + Add New Item, Application Manifest File.  Edit the file to add the regfree COM entries.

Comment: Does this include the file as a Win32 resource or as a .NET resource ? (or is there a difference ?)

Comment: Win32 resource, as "/win32res" strongly suggests.  Yes, there's a big difference, very different format and location in the file.  Windows can only read win32 resources.  You can see them with File + Open + File, pick the .exe